# How to use attribute and insert it as element jquery

Tags: jquery, insert, attributes, element

Is it possible to insert, f.e. to "span", an attribute like this.

```
<span data-text="Hello world"></span>
```

If the event reaches its condition, then script takes information from "data-text" and inserts it into "span".

So, resulting span will be like

```
<span data-text="Hello world">Hello world</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `text` as follow

```
$('span[data-text]').text(function() {
    return $(this).data('text');
});
```

1. `$('span[data-text]')` will select all the `<span>` elements having `data-text` attribute present on them
2. `text()` with callback function is used to iterate over all the matched elements and update their respective `innerText`. You can also use `html()` instead of `text()`.
3. `$(this).data('text')` will retrieve the `data-text` attribute value of the current(`$(this)`) element and returning it from the function will update the innerText.

**Demo**

```js
$('span[data-text]').text(function() {
  return $(this).data('text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-text="Hello world"></span>
<span data-text="GoodBye World!"></span>
<span data-text="Is it Working?"></span>
```

Comment: @NeedHate Welcome! Glad to help